# How to put an onclick on bubbles created by javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of bubbles that are created by javascript and all in one div with the same class. I want to put an onclick on them so that when they are clicked they delete and then make it so that every time you pop one of the bubbles, it adds to a score, and puts that number in the div with the id 'score'

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bubbles</title>
<link href="bubbles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bubbles.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/java.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--background bubbles-->
<div id="b-blue" class="b" data-speed="1"></div>
<div id="b-green" class="b" data-speed="2"></div>
<div id="b-red" class="b" data-speed="4"></div>

<!--bubble text-->
<div id="bText">
    B<br />U<br />B<br />B<br />L<br />E<br />S<br />!
</div>

<!--bubble game-->
<div id="bubbleGame">
    <!-- <div class="bubble"></div> -->
</div>

<!--bubble score and reset-->
<div id="bottomCorner">
    <div id="reload">refresh...</div>
    <div id="score">0</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bubbles Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
makeBubbles();

$(".b").each(function(){        
    var scroller = $(this);
    //alert($(this).data("speed"));
    $(window).scroll(function(event){

        var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
        var ypos = -(0.1 * $(scroller).data("speed") * scrolled) + 'px';
        $(scroller).css('top', ypos);
    });
});
});


function makeBubbles(){
var i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){      
    var newBubble = document.createElement("div");
    $(newBubble).addClass("bubble");
    $("#bubbleGame").append(newBubble);     
    randomize(newBubble);
}
}
```

And this is what I have tried:

```
window.onload = bubbleGame;




function bubble(){
var bubbleburst = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');

for (var i = 0; i< bubbleburst.length; i++){
    bubbleburst[i].onclick = burst; 
}
}

function burst(){
alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: the onclick event bubbles all by it self, you don't have to create bubbles for that ?

Comment: The bubbles are created using jquery on a seperat script sheet. I have to target the bubbles and make it so that they delete upon being clicked. (not using jquery)

Comment: Different type of bubbles, I think...

Answer (score 1):

Use the new on click syntax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bubble', function(evt) {

});
```

Or something like this if you want to limit it to a particular container instead of document-wide:

```
$('#parentDiv').on('click', '.bubble', function(evt) {

});
```

Comment: Thank you. This way does work. Is there another way to acomplish this without using jquery?

Comment: Also, how would I keep track of bubbles deleted after being clicked on in the score div.